# Would this SingleOrDefault() optimization be worthwhile or is it overkill / harmful?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, optimization

I was messing around with LinqToSQL and LINQPad and I noticed that SingleOrDefault() doesn't do any filtering or limiting in the generated SQL (I had almost expected the equivalent of Take(1)).

So Assuming you wanted to protect yourself from large quantities accidentally being returned, would the following snippet be useful or is it a bad idea?

```
// SingleType is my LinqToSQL generated type 
// Singles is the table that contains many SingleType's
// context is my datacontext
public SingleType getSingle(int id)
{
     var query = from s in context.Singles where s.ID == id select s;
     var result = query.Take(2).SingleOrDefault();
     return result;
}
```

As opposed to the normal way I would have done it (notice no .Take(2) )

```
public SingleType getSingle(int id)
{
     var query = from s in Singles where s.ID == id select s;
     var result = query.SingleOrDefault();
     return result;
}
```

I figured with the Take(2), I would still get the functionality of SingleOrDefault() with the added benefit of never having to worry about returning {n} rows accidentally, but I'm not sure if its even worth it unless i'm constantly expecting to accidentally return {n} rows with my query.

So, is this worthwhile?  Is it harmful?  Are there any pro's / con's that I'm not seeing?

Edit:

### SQL Generated without the Take(2)

```
SELECT [t0].[blah], (...) 
FROM [dbo].[Single] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ID] = @p0
```

### SQL Generated with the Take(2)

```
SELECT TOP 2 [t0].[blah], (...) 
FROM [dbo].[Single] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ID] = @p0
```

Also, when I speak of SingleOrDefault's functionality, I specifically desire to have it throw an exception if 2 or more are returned, which is why i'm doing a "Take(2)".  The difference being, without the .Take(2), it will return {n} rows from the database, when it really only needs to return 2 (just enough to make it throw).

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL generated?  I've never verified, but I assume SingleOrDefault will result in a TOP 1.

Comment: TOP 1 will not be sufficient to determine that there is at most one row when there is no unique constaint on the column. So it must be TOP 2 or can be omitted if the column has a unique constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Single` is more of a convenience method to get the single element of a query than a way to limit the number of results.  By using `Single` you are, in effect, saying "I know this query can only have one item, so just give it to me," just like when doing `someArray[0]` when you know there will only be one element.  `SingleOrDefault` adds the ability to return `null` rather than throwing an exception when dealing with sequences of length 0.  You shouldn't be using `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` with queries that may return more than 1 result: an `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown.

If `ID` in your query is the primary key of the table, or a `UNIQUE` column, the database will ensure that the result set contains 1 row or none with no need for a `TOP` clause.

However, if you are selecting on a non-unique / non-key column and want the first result or last result (note that these have no meanings unless you also introduce an `OrderBy`) then you can use `First` or `Last` (which both have `OrDefault` counterparts) to get the SQL you desire:

```
var query = from s in context.Singles 
            where s.Id == id
            orderby s.someOtherColumn
            select s;

var item = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

On a side note, you can save yourself some typing if you are, indeed, doing a query for a single element:

```
var query = from s in context.Singles where s.Id == id select s;
var item = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

can become:

```
var item = context.Singles.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

Comment: You're right, now that I think about it, if I was in a situation where I thought I might return more than one result, I wouldn't be using SingleOrDefault, I'd handle it completely differently.  I suppose this is a classic example of over thinking it

Answer (score 2):

[SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359429.aspx) (and the [IEnumerable<T>.SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) ) both raise an InvalidOperationException if the sequence has more than one element.

Your case above can never happen - it will throw an exception.

---

Edit:

My suggestion here would depend on your usage scenario.  If you think there will be cases where you're going to regularly return more than a few rows from this query, then add the .Take(2) line.  This will give you the same behavior, and the same exception, but eliminate the potential for returning many records from the DB.

However, your use of SingleOrDefault() is suggesting that there should never be >1 row returned.  If that's really the case, I would leave this off and just treat this as an exception.  In my opinion, you're reducing the readability of the code by suggesting that it would be normal to have >2 records when you add .Take(2), and in this case, I don't believe that's true.  I'd take the perf. hit in the exceptional case for the simplicity of leaving it off.

Comment: Right, I specified that, thats why I'm doing a Take(2), however, the  SQL generated from the two are different as I will put in my post

Comment: @Allen: Your post edit shows both being identical.

However, I wouldn't worry about it.  If you have >1 element, this is an exceptional case (and will throw an exception).  Really, if you're in that situation, you have other issues to deal with.  The slight perf. drop before you throw your exception would be less worrisome than why I'm getting duplicated IDs in my database.

Comment: Argh, I messed up the edit, its fixed now, without the .Take(2) you WILL NOT get "top 2", sorry :)

Comment: @Allen: Updated my answer re: your comments.  There is little practical reason to avoid Take(2) if you're worried about it.

Answer (score 2):

You already mentioned the point. If you exspect the query to return a huge number of rows quite often, it might give you a performance gain. But if this is an exceptional case - and `SingleOrDefault()` clearly indicates that - it is not worth the effort. It just pollutes your code and you should document it if you decide to let it in.

**UPDATE**

Just noticed that you are querying the id. I assume it is the primary key and you will get one or zero rows in consequence. So in theory you should not care much about using `Single()`, `First()`, `Take(1)` or whatever. But I would still consider it good design to use `Single()` to explicitly state that you exspect exactly one row. A cohort told me a few weeks ago that they even had a project, where something went terribly wrong and the primary key was no longer unique because of a mayor database malfunction. So better safe than sorry.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, bad example, I addressed this in Gustavo's answer via comment.  Oh and ouch, I never thought of a schema change as something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Allen, is ID the primary key for the Singles table? If it is I don't fully understand your issue, as your second query will return one record or null. And the SQL will be where ID = ###...
Using Take(2).SingleOrDefault() defeats the purpose of SingleOrDefault.

Comment: In this example, yes, and I realize that may be a very bad example since it technically cant return more than one.  Just imagine if it was a "get ... by name" where it could return more than one and you needed to account for that.